# Something wrong with this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, where-clause, having-clause

Is there something wrong with this query?

```
SELECT 
    id,
    ( 6371 * acos(cos(radians(?1)) * cos(radians(latitud)) * cos(radians(longitud) - radians(?2)) + sin(radians(?1)) * sin(radians(latitud)))) AS distance 
FROM usuario_señales 
HAVING (distance < 0.1 AND ancho <= ?3) 
ORDER BY distance;
```

I have a web server in spring boot and I am trying to get the id of the rows in a radius of 1 metes according to the latitud and longitude and with the attribute ancho smaller than the one I pass:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="SELECT id,( 6371 * acos(cos(radians(?1)) * cos(radians(latitud)) * cos(radians(longitud) - radians(?2)) + sin(radians(?1)) * sin(radians(latitud)))) AS distance FROM usuario_señales HAVING (distance < 0.1 AND ancho <= ?3) ORDER BY distance")
```

The error that I get is the following:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ancho' in 'having clause'

There is something wrong with the having clause and how I use it. Any clue? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: HAVING expressions may refer either to source table columns/expressions used in GROUP BY (this clause is absent in your query) or to output columns names/aliases (`ancho` column name/alias is absent in output columns list) or to source table columns/expressions not used in GROUP BY but wrapped with aggregate functon. So the query is wrong.

Comment: So I need to put GROUP BY ancho after the HAVING clause? Because it does't work. Now it's a SQL Syntax error.

Comment: Does `ancho` is a column in `usuario_señales`? If so move the condition by this column to WHERE clause.

Comment: @Akina Thank you! It's solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of your question, it does not look like you want an aggregation query. Instead, you are trying to use the `having` clause to avoid repeating the lengthy computation in the `where` clause: MySQL supports that (even without a `group by` clause), but in that case will let you use only columns from the `select` clause in the `having` clause.

You don't need to use the `having` clause to filter on `ancho`, you can use a regular `where` clause. I think the query you meant to write was:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    ( 6371 * acos(cos(radians(?1)) * cos(radians(latitud)) * cos(radians(longitud) - radians(?2)) + sin(radians(?1)) * sin(radians(latitud)))) AS distance 
FROM usuario_señales 
WHERE ancho <= ?3
HAVING distance < 0.1
ORDER BY distance;
```

I am not fan of this syntax, which relies on MySQL extension to the standard SQL. I would use a subquery instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,
        ( 6371 * acos(cos(radians(?1)) * cos(radians(latitud)) * cos(radians(longitud) - radians(?2)) + sin(radians(?1)) * sin(radians(latitud)))) AS distance 
    FROM usuario_señales 
    WHERE ancho <= ?3
) t
WHERE distance < 0.1 
ORDER BY distance;
```